# Distribution using the Poisson Point Process model

Tags: random, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I need to use the Poisson Point Process (PPP) model to randomly distribute a set of 'objects'; over a given area: Let's say that we have N objects to distribute over an area that has been split equally into S subsections. How might I use PPP to decide whether or not a subsection r (where r ∈ S) contains an object t (where t ∈ N)?

Ideally if anyone has a pseudo code solution then let me know, but I would be grateful for any form of help.

If you need me to be more specific let me know.

Comment: Perhaps start with a simpler problem. In one dimension, do you know the conditional distribution of the event times of a Poisson process given the number of arrivals is $N?$